# How to turn a 2D image into a 3D object?

Tags: python, modifiers, image

I am fairly new to Blender.

I want an half transparent Image (Logo of some company) to have some depth so it looks better rotating. I know there are modifiers like the *Displace* modifier but they don't work in my case, because I must be able to change it to another image afterwards (I am working with a python pipeline that inputs the Image).

Every Tutorial I've found makes the Image irreplaceable after giving it the depth I need.

[image: It should look like this but I want to change the Image after]

Comment: Do you mean that the object is supposed to morph into a second shape? Because it's not clear what you mean by irreplacable

Comment: I want a 3D model of the logo like in the picture but I need to be able to easily replace it with another logo

Comment: Will it be ok if it's high poly?

Comment: Yes I guess so?

Comment: It would be nice if you mentioned why you need it, as advice will be different for 3D printing, gamedev, rendering…

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you have the logos in black and white you can use a displacement modifier with them as a texture on a flat surface
[image]

And then use a boolean to remove the bottom

[image]

You can change the icon by changing the texture used by the displacement mod.

The displacement mod method is brute forcing it and will require a ton of subdivisions. You can give it a remesh modifier with sharp setting at the end to simplify it but it's probably not gonna be perfect for renders.

(This will not work with that image you have. You need the logos in white and the background in black)

For working with 3d logos what you really want is to have them in .svg format so you can just import them and and extrude them to give them thickness.

For either method your sample image will not work, You need clean flat colors without that kind of soft shade. You'd need to use an image editing program to heighten the contrast and get something like this for the displacement
[image]

Inkscape can turn images into .svg for the second method. Here's a tutorial on that:
https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=FkP4W7n8O24